# I'm trying to delete an object in my world that is saved in an ArrayList but it doesn't work

Tags: java

I use dyn4j physics engine (although I don't think it's relevant for my question).

I don't get any errors but if I press the right mouse button on one of the objects it doesn't delete the object.

Does anyone know what might be the problem?

Here I add the objects to my world:

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

    double x = e.getPoint().getX()/100;
    double y = e.getPoint().getY()/100;

    if (addBlocks.isSelected()) {
        BodyFixture fblock = new BodyFixture(Geometry.createRectangle(1,1));
        dblock = new Body();
        if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
            dblock.addFixture(fblock);
            dblock.getTransform().setTranslation(x,y);
            dblock.setMass(MassType.NORMAL);
            dblock.getFixture(0).setRestitution(0.3);
            world.addBody(dblock);
            gameObjects.add(new GameObject("dirtblock.png", dblock, new Vector2(0, 0), 0.8));
        }
    }
}
```

And here I'm trying to delete them:

```
if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3) {
    for (int i = 0; i < gameObjects.size(); i++) {
        if (gameObjects.get(i).contains(e.getPoint())) {
            world.removeBody(gameObjects.get(i).body);
            gameObjects.remove(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide more details about your problem, i.e. what happens when you're trying to delete an object, any relevant error messages, if any,

Comment: When you add objects you do some kind of scaling by calculating a new x and y from e.getPoint() but in your remove code you use e.getPoint() directly without scaling. Could this be a reason the if clause is never true?

Answer (score 0):

Usually when you are deleting items with index in a loop you start the loop at the end of the collection due to indices changing i.e. try this:

```
if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3) {
    for (int i = gameObjects.size() - 1; i >= 0 ; i--) {
        if (gameObjects.get(i).contains(e.getPoint())) {
            world.removeBody(gameObjects.get(i).body);
            gameObjects.remove(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, when i try that i get an error in the line if(gameObjects.get(i).contains(e.getPoint())){                        
     Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out-of-bounds for length 1

Comment: Will fix the code, im no java expert tho :) Start the loop with size()-1.

Comment: The errors are gone now but still nothing happens when i try to delete an object

Comment: Are you sure you are getting in the if scope and actually calling `remove()` function ?

Comment: I just tested it and no he doesnt get into the if scope

Comment: Cool, glad I could help. And I still think you would have come to the issue you solved with the code in the answer.

Comment: You may add an explanation **why** people are usually doing it this way (due to indices changing) to your answer.